# Material UI navigating other pages using Accout Menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router

I'm trying to create logged user menu with Account menu but I couldn't figure out the link navigation. I've tried to use <MenuItem component={ Link } to="/editProfile"> but it does not seem to work. I've also tried wrapping MenuLink's around with Link tags but it also did not work.

[image: AccoutMenu]

```
I want to be able to click those links.

Here is Navbar code that Account Menu in it:

import React, { Profiler, useState } from 'react';
import { RiMenu3Line, RiCloseLine } from 'react-icons/ri';
import { NavLink, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import logo from '../../assets/logoo.png'; 
import './navbar.css';  

import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import Logout from '@mui/icons-material/Logout';
import { Favorite } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Link } from '@mui/material';



import usericon from '../../assets/UserIcon.png'; 

function AccountMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Tooltip title="Account settings" >
          <IconButton
            onClick={handleClick}
            size="large"
            sx={{ ml: 2 }}
            aria-controls={open ? 'account-menu' : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
          >
            <img src={usericon} alt='logo' width={50} height={50} />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </Box>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        id="account-menu"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onClick={handleClose}
        PaperProps={{
          elevation: 0,
          sx: {
            overflow: 'visible',
            filter: 'drop-shadow(0px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.32))',
            background: 'var(--color-dark-blue)',
            color: 'white',
            mt: 1.5,
            ml: -2,
            '& .MuiAvatar-root': {
              width: 32,
              height: 32,
              ml: -0.5,
              mr: 1,
            },
            '&:before': {
              content: '""',
              display: 'block',
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0,
              right: 14,
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
              bgcolor: 'background.paper',
              transform: 'translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)',
              zIndex: 0,
              background: 'var(--color-dark-blue)',
            },
          },
        }}
        transformOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
      >
        <MenuItem component={Link} href="/editProfile">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Avatar fontSize="small" style={{ color: "var(--color-orange)", background: 'var(--color-dark-blue)' }} />
          </ListItemIcon>
          Profile
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem component={Link} href="/favorites">
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Favorite fontSize="small" style={{ color: "var(--color-orange)" }} />
          </ListItemIcon>
          Favorites
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem component={Link} href="/" style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Logout fontSize="small" style={{ color: "var(--color-orange)" }} />
          </ListItemIcon>
          Log out
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}



const LinksMenu = () => (
  <>
    <p><a href='#link1'>About us</a></p>
    <p><a href='#link2'>Contact us</a></p>
  </>
)



const Navbar = () => {
  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className='navbar'> 
      
      <div className='navbar-links'>

        <a href="/" aria-label="Logo" class="navbar-main__logo">
          <div className='navbar-links_logo'>
            <img src={logo} alt='logo' />
          </div>
        </a>

        <div className='navbar-links_container'>
          <LinksMenu />
        </div>

        <div class="fill-remaining-space"></div>

        <div className='navbar-sign'>
          <p><NavLink to='/signIn'>Sign in</NavLink></p>
          <button type='button'>Register</button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <AccountMenu/>
        </div>

        <div className='navbar-menu'>
          {toggleMenu
            ? <RiCloseLine color='#fff' size={27} onClick={() => setToggleMenu(false)} /> 
            : <RiMenu3Line color='#fff' size={27} onClick={() => setToggleMenu(true)} /> 
          }
          {toggleMenu && ( 
            <div className='navbar-menu_container scale-up-center'>
              <div className='navbar-menu_container_links'>
                <LinksMenu />
              </div>
            <div className='navbar-menu_container_links_sign'>
              <p>Sign in</p>
              <button type='button'>Sign up</button>
            </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Here is the App.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import Favorites from './pages/Favorites';
import EditProfile from './pages/EditProfile';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='R'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/signIn" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorites />} />
          <Route path="/editProfile" element={<EditProfile />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: <MenuItem component={ Link } to="/editProfile"> should work. Where are you mounting your menu>

Comment: @RichardHpa I'm trying to mount it on the Navbar if you asked this.

Comment: When I changed "to" to "href" it worked... I don't know why, maybe something with Routes or BrowseRouter.

Comment: `<MenuItem component={ Link } to="/editProfile">...` is correct. Where are you rendering this `AccountMenu` component? I don't see it rendered in `App`... so where is it being mounted and rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm rendering it on a Navigation bar. I edited the first code.

Comment: Ok, and where is `Navbar` being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell of the code so far I see 2 issues:

1. You are not rendering the `Navbar` component within the routing context being provided to the app.
2. The `Navbar` component is rendering `@mui/material` `Link` components instead of `react-router-dom` `Link` components.

Fix the links in the `Navbar` component, the `MenuItem` components should render the `NavLink` component and take a `to` prop instead of `href`:

```
...
import { NavLink, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function AccountMenu() {
  ...

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      ...
      <Menu
        ...
      >
        <MenuItem component={NavLink} to="/editProfile">
          ...
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem component={NavLink} to="/favorites">
          ...
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem component={NavLink} to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          ...
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Render the `Navbar` component within the router.

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../path/to/Navbar';
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import Favorites from './pages/Favorites';
import EditProfile from './pages/EditProfile';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='R'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar /> // <-- render inside routing context
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/signIn" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorites />} />
          <Route path="/editProfile" element={<EditProfile />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```